# Quickest way to put up a mobile-phone friendly website displaying SQL Server data?

Tags: sql-server, mobile

What is the quickest way to put up a mobile-friendly page displaying data pulled out by a query from a SQL Server 2005 database?

I have .NET coding experience and know how to code up HTML, but XML and PHP are like Greek to me.

The web server I have has IIS installed, and I am open to any good software editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need fine-grain control of your markup, and a quick and easy way to display some data.

Suggest using [WebMatrix](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/). Create a new website. Connect to your database, and create the markup you want. You'll need to [get to know the Razor syntax](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx); the learning curve isn't too bad.  You'll have all the tools you'd need. Here's [getting started with WebMatrix](http://www.microsoft.com/web/post/web-development-101-part-1-getting-started-with-webmatrix).